# Static Resource Conditional Image Display in PageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

This is the name and path of Static Resource (ComplianceImage.Zip) File "ComplianceImages/Yes.png" , "ComplianceImages/No.png" etc..I am unable to display image in column. Pls help

```
<apex:column headervalue="Image"> 
               <apex:image value ="{!IF(Asq.Obj.Compliance_Status__c=="No", URLFOR($Resource.ComplianceImages,'Yes.Png'),
                                     IF(Asq.Obj.Compliance_Status__c=="Approved", URLFOR($Resource.ComplianceImages,'Yes.Png'),
                                     IF(Asq.Obj.Compliance_Status__c=="Candidate Submission (Requires Verification)", URLFOR($Resource.ComplianceImages,'RV.Png'),
                                     IF(Asq.Obj.Compliance_Status__c=="More Required", URLFOR($Resource.ComplianceImages,'MR.Png'),
                                     IF(Asq.Obj.Compliance_Status__c=="Rejected", URLFOR($Resource.ComplianceImages,'NA.Png'))}" width="20" height="20"/>                 
            </apex:column>
```

Comment: what is the issue? your code looks good. Can you pls open dev console(or Press F+12) check console any error you are getting?

Comment: No Error. Image is not being displayed. Displayed as "Broken" file in column of table

Comment: Pls add screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on your zip file hierarchy.

In your local, Open the zip(open, don't extract), if you see your files right after opening the file, your code is fine. If you have to enter one level deep( a folder called ComplianceImages), then you have to add ComplianceImages/Yes.png to your code.

```
URLFOR($Resource.ComplianceImages,'ComplianceImages/Yes.Png')
```

Comment: No there are no further folders

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your zip file opened in Winrar or any other utility?

Answer (score 1):

I just missed this "blah blah, '/Yes.png')
It works now. Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/37627)

Comment: It does provide an answer to the question. I missed a '/' in the path. So i recognised it by myself. Thats what i specified in previous comment.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Just trying to make sure your answer is generic so that others with the same problem can benefit from it as well.  :-)